# React: how do you know that a parent of one component is another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, class, react-redux

I have one element that works with custom (my) objects:

```
<MyElement1 />
<MyElement2 />
<MyElement3 />
<br></br>
<MyElement4 />
```

This objects are elements inherited from some base class:

```
class MyElement1 extends MyElementBase1...
class MyElement2 extends MyElementBase1...
class MyElement3 extends MyElementBase2...
class MyElement4 extends MyElementBase2...
```

and

```
class MyElementBase1 extends MyElementBase...
class MyElementBase2 extends MyElementBase...
...
class MyElementBase extends React.Component...
```

I'm going over the objects as follows:

```
for (const obj of mydata.props.children)
{
...
}
```

**Tell me how to determine that the object is a child of a base class?**

For example:

```
if obj.type instanceof MyElementBase2...
```

result:

```
<MyElement1 /> - false
<MyElement2 /> - false
<MyElement3 /> - true
<br></br> - false
<MyElement4 /> - true
```

or

```
if obj.type instanceof Component...
```

result:

```
<MyElement1 /> - true
<MyElement2 /> - true
<MyElement3 /> - true
<br></br> - false
<MyElement4 /> - true
```

Comment: I’m curious. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, to request data from my components, ignoring the standard components.